# mvc dynamically change stylebundle on incoming host domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dns

Been trying to work through this problem for a bit now.  It is MVC4 C#

The jist:
I require change the entire site layout based which domain contacted the server.

The details:
My initial thoughts were that if someone entered on "bobsdiner.com" vs "susansCafe.com" that i would be able to put some logic in app_start to get the host name and then set the stylebundle to the correct stylesheet (additionally setting a _layout view would be fantastic as well).  I have found out that IIS7 will not allow access to the request object in app_start any longer.  I am a bit of a loss of where to go next where i can have a central code section instead of changing this for every controller (i have about 15 of them).  In addition to all this i would like to be able to access the db with the host name as i do have a table that contains domain names and the stylesheet names.

any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would forgo trying to change the style bundle and re-purpose the context switcher.

in the app start of the global asax, you can do something like this

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Bobs")
        {
            ContextCondition = ctx => ctx.Request.Url.Host.Contains("bobsdiner")
        });
```

So if you make your site look like susanscafe using the _layout.cshtml, and then create a bobs diner version by using _layout.Bobs.cshtml.  you can specify the different look and feel there to get the effect you want.